# How to draw BiDi text in custom view using StaticLayout

Tags: android, text, drawing, bidi

In a custom android View I'm painting several user input texts that may be Bi-Directional. For example Hebrew or Arabic mixed with English text or numbers. To draw the text I basically use the view's Canvas, a TextPaint and a StaticLayout. 
The actual code is rather complex and spread out, but the bit that paints the text looks like so:

```
TextPaint _paint = getPaint();
Canvas _canvas = ...; // the canvas passed in the View.onDraw(Canvas canvas) method
PointF l = locationCenter(); // the location at which the center of text should be painted
int alignment = getAlignment(); // for this element, can vary for each element.
PointF textSize = getTextBounds(); // the bounding box of the text
String text = userInputText(); // actually some user input BiDi text
                switch (alignment) {
                    case 0:
                        _paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
                        l.x += textSize.x / 2.0f;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        _paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
                        l.x -= 1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        _paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
                        l.x += (textSize.x + 1);
                        break;
                }

                StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, _paint, (int) Math.ceil(textSize.x + 0.5f), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
                _canvas.translate(l.x, l.y);
                layout.draw(_canvas);
                _canvas.translate(-l.x, -l.y);
```

This works OK for LTR or RTL only text, but not for Bidi text which appears garbled. The odd thing is that when I force alignment to be 0 (resulting in _paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.Left) it usually seems to work OK (=as far as I can test). However, making alignment conditionnally 0 when text contains BiDi (or RTL) characters, does **not** work. It seems either Canvas, Paint or StaticLayout is preserving state.

I tried using a BidiFormatter like so:

```
                BidiFormatter.Builder builder = new BidiFormatter.Builder();
                builder.stereoReset(true);
                android.support.v4.text.BidiFormatter formatter = builder.build(); 
                String text = formatter.unicodeWrap(userInputText());
                // proceed as above
```

But that makes no difference (still garbled text).

Any idea how to reliably paint (many) BiDi texts in a custom view?
And any idea why forcing alignment to Paint.Align.Left for **all texts** would seem to fix the problem.
This should preferrably work from android 4.0 onwards, but at least 4.2 or 4.4.
Thanks in advance.

I got it more or less working by using Character.getDirectionality to test for rtl chars in a text:

```
public static boolean containsRtlChar(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        int c = text.codePointAt(i);
        int direction = Character.getDirectionality(c);
        if ((direction == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT) || (direction == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC) || (direction == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_EMBEDDING) || (direction == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_OVERRIDE))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then based on that force alignment to Left (

```
                if (containsRtlChars(text)) {
                    alignment = TextStyle.textAlignLeft;
                }
```

This results in text containing a RTL char to be OK, although with a fixed (center) alignment.

Comment: I sorted out why conditional forcing alignment for strings containing rtl chars did not work: I used StaticLayout.isRtlCharAt(int) to check whether a string contains any rtl chars, but this returns false for a string containing hebrew chars but starts with a number. (seems a StaticLayout bug to me). Using Character.getDirectionality works OK. => there's no state preserved by Canvas, Paint or StaticLayout as I assumed.

Comment: Can you please share the complete solution? Also, does your solution works for center aligned mixed direction texts?